# "Urlaub" oder "Ferien"

Tags: translation, word-usage, word-choice

In my German textbook there is a sentence with "Ferien".

"*Königliche Ferien im Schatten von Burgen und Schlössern*."

I consulted my Wörterbuch and found "Urlaub". I am curious which word of these two is more common according to you.

Comment: Ich konnte nicht recht haben, aber "Ferien" heißt nur das man nicht arbeitet, und "Urlaub" heißt das man reist.

Comment: @Bregalad Das wäre ja großartig - laut dem Bundesurlaubsgesetz haben wir alle Anspruch auf Urlaub. Nur wird damit bezahlte arbeitsfreie Zeit gemeint und nicht Reisen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ferien and Urlaub can have slightly different meanings.

Employees (Arbeitnehmer) have Urlaub (paid time off). Teachers (Lehrer), pupils and non-college students (Schüler) have Ferien (vacation, holidays). College students (Studenten) are always busy, they only have vorlesungsfreie Zeit (no classes).

In combination with fahren or fliegen, you can use either Urlaub or Ferien:

> Wir fahren in den Urlaub. / Wir fahren in die Ferien.

When used to designate a time or place, there is a difference:

> In den Ferien will ich viele Bücher lesen.

This means you want to read a lot of books, maybe staying at home. You could also travel and read.

> Im Urlaub will ich viele Bücher lesen.

This implies (to me) that you go somewhere on vacation.

You can also say "Urlaub machen" as a synonym for going on vacation, but "Ferien machen" sounds odd to me.

Comment: Ich glaube auch Lehrer haben Ferien.

Comment: @Ludi Guter Punkt. Ergänzt.

Comment: College students are always busy? Erm, that’s not the stereotype I know …

Comment: We don’t use vacation in uk, just holiday. eg summer holidays from school.

Answer (score 8):

I hope it's ok when I answer in German. (Ich kann mich in meiner Muttersprache besser ausdrücken)

### Ferien

Das Wort wurde im 15. Jahrhundert vom lateinischen »fēriae« (Plur.) (Festtage; Feiertage, an denen keine Geschäfte wahrgenommen werden; Ruhetage) entlehnt.

Schüler und Studenten haben Ferien. Die Ferien (die es übrigens auch im Deutschen nur im Plural gibt) sind also die unterrichtsfreie Zeit von Schülern und Studenten.

Nachdem die Zeiten, an denen an Schulen und Universitäten unterrichtet wird, gesetzlich vorgegeben sind, gibt es Ferien auch nur zu bestimmten Zeiten, und man bezeichnet einzelne Ferien auch nach jener Zeit, in der sie stattfinden:

- Sommerferien = Ferien im Sommer. Sie liegen bei Schülern zwischen zwei Schuljahren und bei Studenten nach dem Ende des Sommersemesters und vor dem Beginn des Wintersemesters.
- Semesterferien: Bei Schülern zwischen dem 1. und 2. Halbjahr desselben Schuljahres, bei Studenten nach dem Ende des Wintersemesters und vor Beginn des Sommersemesters. (Es gibt auch Schulen, bei denen das Schuljahr in drei Trimester unterteilt ist, z.B. bei den Sängerknaben in Wien, da gibt es stattdessen Trimesterferien)
- Weihnachtsferien: Jene Ferien, in die das Weihnachtsfest fällt. Die Weihnachtsferien enden nach dem 6. Jänner (6. Jänner = Heilige drei Könige).
- Osterferien: Jene Ferien, in die das Osterfest fällt.

(Es gibt noch weitere Ferien, teilweise auch abhängig von der Region und/oder Schule bzw. Uni)

Allerdings gibt es auch in großen Betrieben Ferien. Das sind Zeiten, in denen das Werk für typischerweise ein oder zwei Wochen stillsteht, das ist häufig rund um den Jahreswechsel, also zur Weihnachtszeit der Fall. Man spricht dann von *Werksferien* (auch ohne Fugen-s: *Werkferien*).

---

### Urlaub

Das im 8. Jahrhundert belegte altdeutsche Wort »urloub« entwickelte sich einerseits zum »Urlaub«, andererseits aber auch zur »Erlaubnis«. Denn der *urloub* war die Erlaubnis eines Soldaten oder eines anderen Bediensteten, vorübergehend dem Dienst fern zu bleiben.

Urlaub können, in seiner ursprünglichen Bedeutung, also nur nichtselbstständige Erwerbstätige nehmen. Dabei wird diese Erlaubnis individuell erteilt. Das heißt, jeder Arbeiter oder Angestellte nimmt zu ganz individuellen Zeiten Urlaub, unabhängig von allen anderen.

Unter ganz bestimmten Voraussetzungen (z.B. Beerdigung eines nahen Verwandten) können auch Schüler, die eigentlich nur Ferien, aber keinen Urlaub haben, beurlaubt werden.

---

Der wesentliche Unterschied ist also:

**Ferien:** Die Zeit ist fremdbestimmt und gilt für eine große Gruppe.
**Urlaub:** Die Zeit bestimmt jeder selbst (in Absprache mit dem Vorgesetzten) und sie gilt völlig individuell.

---

Daneben haben sich beide Begriffe auch als Bezeichnung für Freizeit etabliert, die man reisend verbringt: Man macht in Griechenland Urlaub, oder macht in Spanien Ferien. Man fährt auch auf oder in Urlaub oder in die Ferien.

Bleibt noch eine Frage:

Haben Lehrer Urlaub oder Ferien?

Lehrer haben eine Freizeit, die sie nicht selbst bestimmen können, und die für alle von ihnen vorgegeben wird. Daher haben Lehrer (und Kindergartenpädagogen und Unilektoren) Ferien.

Wenn der Lektor an derUni aber auch als Forschungsmitarbeiter an der Uni angestellt ist, ruht in den Ferien nur seine Lehrtätigkeit. Wenn er aber ganz von der Uni fern bleiben will, muss er dennoch um Urlaub ansuchen.

---

### Abbreviated English translation

The essential difference is:

**Holiday:** The time is determined by others, such as the society or country, and applies to a large group.

**Vacation:** The time of determined by a person himself (in consultation with the supervisor) and it applies completely individually.

In addition, both terms have been established as a term for leisure, the time one spends traveling (or not).

Comment: The question was written in English, so you might want to provide a (condensed) English translation to your (excellent) German answer.

Comment: @TomAu: My English is not the best and you have the reputation to edit my answer. So if you want add an english translation, or post it as a new answer.

Comment: Auch Lehrer haben in den Ferien nach Ansicht der Kultusminister (zumindest des bayerischen) nicht *per se* frei. Die Ferien sollen zur Vor- und Nachbereitung, Korrektur, Fortbildung etc. verwendet werden. Auch Lehrern steht nur ein gewisser Erholungsurlaub zur Verfügung, den sie ausschließlich während der Ferien in Anspruch nehmen dürfen. Sie sind lediglich darin herausgehoben, dass sie nicht täglich am Arbeitsplatz erscheinen müssen.

Comment: @TomAu: Vielen Dank! Ich habe nur die Formatierung angepasst. Danke!

Comment: Zumindest in Deutschland wird meines Wissens der Begritf "Semesterferien" (bzw. generelp "Semester") überhaupt nicht im Zusammenhang mit *Schülern* verwendet (sondern nur bei Studenten bzw. tertiären Bildungseinrichtungen). Man denkt eigentlich nur in "Schuljahren", die zwar organisatorisch in "Halbjahre" unterteilt sein mögen, jedoch nicht notwendigerweise durch Ferien getrennt.

Comment: Ebenso scheint zumindest in Deutschland der Sprachgebrauch "Semesterferien" bei Studenten als "Ferien zwischen zwei (beliebigen aufeinanderfolgenden) Semestern" zu verstehen. Die Zeit zwischen SoSe und WiSe sind also genauso Semesterferien wie die Zeit zwischen WiSe und SoSe. (Freilich ist das umgangssprachlich, denn offiziell grenzen die Semester lückenlos aneinander und es gibt nur eine "vorlesungsfreie Zeit", die sich mehrere Wochen über die Semestergrenzen erstreckt und die für Studenten je nach Hochschule und Fachrichtung Prüfungen sowie die Arbeit an Projekten beinhalten kann.)

Answer (score 3):

Ferien translates better as "holiday." That is, "time off" for work, school, or whatever it is you are normally doing, typically mandated by the country or society.

Urlaub translates better as "vacation," that is, a chance to "vacate" your home or place of work to "travel."

Normally, "Urlauben" (vacations) take place during your "Ferien" (holiday) time. Unless, perhaps, you were combining an "Urlaub" with a business trip.

But the reverse is not true. Not every Ferien (holiday) implies an Urlaub (trip), which means that "Ferien" is more common.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small hint:

While the given answers are pretty good, i want to point out that in some areas of southern Germany as well as Switzerland "Ferien" is used **instead** of the word "Urlaub". A swiss colleague of mine insists he is having "Ferien" instead of "Urlaub".

Answer (score 1):

Both words are commonly used but have slightly different meanings. "Ferien" like "Schulferien" or "Sommerferien" (school holidays and summer holidays) is when you don't have to work or do not need to go to school. "Urlaub" more or less descirbes the process of driving or flying somewhere for e.g. one or two in your "Ferien".

Comment: Ich glaube das stimmt nicht. Als ich noch an der Universität arbeitete, ging es immer um die, mir noch zustehende, Urlaubszeit.